# mvc3 - how to update the action attribute for Html.BeginForm() from the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In an .ASPX View (not Razor) ...Is it possible... or... How can I modify the action on

```
    Html.BeginForm("**ACTION**", "controllername",  FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formId" }))
```

of a view from an ActionResult of a Controller just before calling the view?

Comment: Thanks Subha for updating the formatting on my question.

Comment: The below responses only work in Razor Views, I'm using .aspx Views on this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for the dynamically assign action name.

```
@{
    String actionName = /*Assign action name based on the applying condition or using ViewBag you can also get it from controller.*/;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName, "Basic"))
{

}
```